# Android app closes saying Unfortunately app has stopped

Tags: android-sqlite

I have made an application of database in which I am using a pre-created database. This app is to display the download links for the e-books of cse but when I move to intent 2 after clicking on button on Myappactivity.java, then error comes and app stops.
Thanks in Advance to all for replying.

**Myappactivity.java**

```
    package com.nic;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MyappActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    LinearLayout l;
    EditText name ;
    Spinner sub ;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    RadioButton i_yr;
    RadioButton ii_yr;
    RadioButton iii_yr;
    RadioButton iv_yr;

    String sub2[] = {"Digital Electronics","Electronic Devices and                                   Circuits","Data Structures and Algorithms","Discrete Mathematical Structures","Mathematics        III","Internet Technology","Principles of Prog Language","Microprocessor and Interfaces","Object Oriented Programming Languages","Computer Architecture","Statistics and Probability Theory","Management Information Systems"};
    String sub3[] = {"Software Engineering","System Software Engineering","Database Management System","Computer Graphics","Advanced Java","Advanced Data Structures","Operating Systems","Computer Networks","Design and Analysis of Algorithms","Embedded Systems","Theory Of Computation","Multimedia Systems"};
    String sub4[] = {"Compiler Construction","Data Mining and Warehousing","Advanced Logic Systems","Artifical Intelligence","Advanced Software Engineering","Real Time Systems","Information and Security Systems","CAD for VLSI","Advanced Computer Architecture","Distributed Systems"}; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Layout);
         l.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
         name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
         sub = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.subject);
         i_yr = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.i_year);
         ii_yr = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.ii_year);
         iii_yr = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.iii_year);
         iv_yr = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.iv_year);
    }

    public void onrbClicked (View v) {

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();

        switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.i_year:{
            if (checked){
                ArrayAdapter<String> ob = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,sub3));
                sub.setAdapter(ob);
            }
        }break;

        case R.id.ii_year:{
            if (checked){
                ArrayAdapter<String> ob = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,sub2));
                sub.setAdapter(ob);
            }

        }break;

        case R.id.iii_year:{
            if (checked){
                ArrayAdapter<String> ob = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,sub3));
                sub.setAdapter(ob);
            }
        }break;

        case R.id.iv_year:{
            if (checked){
                ArrayAdapter<String> ob = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,sub4));
                sub.setAdapter(ob);
            }
        }  
        break ;
        }
    }

    public void ok (View v){

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
        b.putString("subject", sub.getSelectedItem().toString());
        Intent i = new Intent(MyappActivity.this,Showbooks.class);
        i.putExtras(b); 
        startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

**Showbooks.java**

```
package com.nic;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Showbooks extends Activity {

    TextView tV ;
    ListView lview;
    private Cursor employees;
    private MyDatabase db;
    ExpandableListView lView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nextview);
        tV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tV);
        lview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        db = new MyDatabase(this);
        employees = db.getBooks(); // you would not typically call this on the main thread


        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                employees, 
                new String[] {"book_name"}, 
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

        lview.setAdapter(adapter);


        tV.setText("Welcome " +bundle.getCharSequence("name")+
                ("\n You want book names of - "+bundle.getCharSequence("subject")));

    }

    @Override   protected void onDestroy()
    {       
        super.onDestroy();      
        employees.close();      
        db.close(); 

    }
}
```

**MyDatabase.java**

```
package com.nic;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;


    import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

    public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cse_books.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        public MyDatabase(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

            // you can use an alternate constructor to specify a database location 
            // (such as a folder on the sd card)
            // you must ensure that this folder is available and you have permission
            // to write to it
            //super(context, DATABASE_NAME, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        public Cursor getBooks() {

            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

            String [] sqlSelect = {"book_name", "down_link"}; 
            String sqlTables = "csebooks";
        //    String [] sub_name = {""+subject};
        //    String whereClause = "sub_name = ?";


            qb.setTables(sqlTables);

            Cursor c = db.query("csebooks", sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);


            c.moveToFirst();
            return c;

        }

    }
```

**main.xml**

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your Name"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.04" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/i_year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onrbClicked"
            android:text="I Year" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/ii_year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onrbClicked"
            android:text="II Year" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/iii_year"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onrbClicked"
            android:text="III Year" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/iv_year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:onClick="onrbClicked"
            android:text="IV Year" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/subject"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Select your Subject" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="ok"
            android:text="SUBMIT" />

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**nextview.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.07"
            android:text="List of Books"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error given by the CatLog for your application? This should give you a big hint on where your app failed by printing the exception text in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you copied database from assets location to local storage (i.e., inside app data folder)???
I had used a DatabaseHelper class to do that.
The code is as follows:

***DatabaseHelper.java***

```
package com.package;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {

     //Using Existing Db
     private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.package/databases/";

     private static String DB_NAME = <database_name>;

     private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

     private final Context myContext;



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context; //Using Existing Db
    }
     /**
      * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
      * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
    //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

    //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
    //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.


    this.getReadableDatabase();

    try {   
    copyDataBase();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    throw new Error("Error copying database");

    }
    }

    }

     /**
      * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
      * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
      */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

    //database does't exist yet.
    }

    if(checkDB != null){

    checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

     /**
      * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
      * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
      * This is done by transfering bytestream.
      * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

    }
     public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }


}
```

Then I have used the database like this:

```
myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle){
        //throw sqle;
    }

    db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Then you can use cursor to perform query.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Thank u vry mch
But where to write the code by creating object of DatabaseHelper class and using the functions in it.

Comment: You mean my second code segment??? You use that in the activity where you want to query the database.